# How to set the `Accept-Language` header for one test in Playwright?

Tags: playwright-test

How can I set the `Accept-Language` header **for one [test call](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-test#test-call)**
in [Playwright](https://playwright.dev/) ?

E.g.:

```
import { test, expect } from '@playwright/test';

test( 'language is interpreted correctly', async function({ page, context }) {

    // -----
    // HERE: Set the `Accept-Language` header to 'de-DE,de;q=0.9,en;q=0.8' somehow ?
    // -----
    
    const response = await page.goto( 'http://example.com' );
    const acceptLanguageHeader = await response.request().headerValue('Accept-Language');
    expect( acceptLanguageHeader ).toBe( 'de-DE,de;q=0.9,en;q=0.8' );
    expect( somethingThatDependsOnTheLanguage ).toBe( true );
});
```

#### What I found, which doesn't work:

I know I can set extra headers with [page.setExtraHTTPHeaders()](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-set-extra-http-headers),
but that apparently doesn't overwrite the `Accept-Language` header.

I know I can configure [TestOptions](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-testoptions) with:

- [playwright.config.js](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-configuration) for the default context, or
- [testConfig.use](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-testconfig#test-config-use) or [testProject.use](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-testproject#test-project-use) for all tests,

but I want to test different settings in each `test()` call.

E.g. this **doesn't work**:

```
test( 'try modified accept-language header', async function({ page, context }) {

    await context.setExtraHTTPHeaders({
        'Accept-Language': 'de-DE,de;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
        'some-extra-header': 'some extra header value from context',
    });

    await page.setExtraHTTPHeaders({
        'Accept-Language': 'de-DE,de;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
        'some-extra-header': 'some extra header value from page',
    });

    const response = await page.goto( 'http://example.com' );

    console.log('headers:', response.request().headers()); // <-- 'accept-language' is 'en-US',

    const acceptLanguageHeader = await response.request().headerValue('Accept-Language');
    expect( acceptLanguageHeader ).toBe( 'de-DE,de;q=0.9,en;q=0.8' ); // <-- Received: "en-US"
});
```

I have seen the answers to ["How to add custom headers ..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62605422/how-to-add-custom-headers-in-playwright)
and ["How to change default language ..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67238821/how-to-change-default-language-chromium-firefox-using-playwright) and other examples,
but

- they are creating their own [browser](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-browser)
  and [browser.context](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-browsercontext) (like `const context = await browser.newContext( ... )`),
  and
- they are not using a [test call](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-test#test-call), and
- don't show where they get the `browser` instance from.
- *(Probably they are not using the [playwright test-runner](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-fixtures). I don't know how they are running their tests)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [browserContext.route()](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-browsercontext#browser-context-route)
to modify network requests in each test individually.

E.g.:

```
test( 'Example for browserContext.route()', async function({ page, context }) {

    // -- modify the request
    await context.route('**/*', (route, request) => {
        route.continue({
            headers: {
                ...request.headers(),
                'accept-language': 'de-DE,de;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
            }
        });
    });

    // -- navigate
    await page.goto( urlOfMyWebsite );
    
    // -- test if language of accept-header is correctly used
    expect( someContent ).toBe( translatedToGerman );
});
```

[RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) is also allowed to match the url, e.g.:

```
await context.route(/^\/[-a-z]+$/, (route, request) => { ...
```

**Note** that the header name seems to be case-sensitive, and might behave weird.
I found different tests behave in different ways, for example (I could not always reproduce this in different environments):

- setting only `'Accept-Language': 'de-DE'` *might* result in e.g. `Received: "en-US, de-DE"`.
- setting both: `'Accept-Language': 'de-DE', 'accept-language': 'de-DE'` *might* result in `Received: "de-DE, de-DE"`.

Comment: Looks like this works with chromium and firefox, but not webkit.